# EF Core - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, sql-server-2017, ef-core-3.1

Trying to do a dotnet ef database update on an object that has some DateTimeOffset members. But I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Here is the model I am trying to map to sql:

```
 public int SessionId { get; set; }
 public int SpeakerId { get; set; }
 public string Title { get; set; }
 public TimeSpan Length { get; set; }
 public DateTimeOffset ScheduledAt { get; set; }
 public DateTimeOffset Submitted { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; }
```

Below is my dbcontext code:

```
    public DbSet<Core.Models.Session> Sessions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating (ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

        var dateTimeOffsetConverter = new ValueConverter<DateTimeOffset, string> (
                v => v.ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"),
                v => DateTimeOffset.Parse (v));

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Core.Models.Session> ()
            .Property (s => s.ScheduledAt)
            .HasColumnType ("datetimeoffset");

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Core.Models.Session> ()
            .Property (s => s.Submitted)
            .HasColumnType ("datetimeoffset");


        modelBuilder.Entity<Core.Models.Session> ().HasData (MockSessionData.Sessions);

    }
```

Below is the SQL script that is generated to create some fake data:

```
INSERT INTO [Sessions] ([SessionId], [Description], [Length], [ScheduledAt], [SpeakerId], [Submitted], [Title])

VALUES (1, N'overview of new features of dotnet core 3.1', '00:40:00', '2020-08-03T13:00:00.0000000+01:00', 1, '2019-12-03T13:00:00.0000000+01:00', N'dotnet core 3.1');
```

I have tried to use the script generated but dotnet ef to insert the data into sql manually but I get the same error. I did manage to get it working on when I used the following format using the SQL `CAST()` method:

```
CAST('2019-12-03 13:00:00.0000000 +01:00' AS datetimeoffset)
```

but I am unsure how to do this using ef core or if thats even possible?

I am using the sql server docker container.

System specs:

dotnet core 3.1

SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU13) (KB4466404) - 14.0.3048.4 (X64)

vs code 1.44.2

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that the issue was not the datetimeoffset but the timespan as I was adding other timespan values that were over a day. Which resulted in a insert script that would format the timespan value to '1.00:30:00'. This was causing the conversion error.

Comment: And what is the solution?